# Cell values ​do not update

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I want to update every minute a cell with data from a HTML link. The problem is that the value does not update unless I manually empty the cell or make changes to the script. I tried to add `NOW()` to the script but the cells do not update. I do not know much about JavaScript. Could someone explain to me what and where in the script I should add or change something?

This is my script:

```
function DataFromDomoticz() {
  var now = new Date();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LUCHTVOCHTIGHEID_V2').getRange('A1').setValue(now);
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LUCHTVOCHTIGHEID_V2').getRange('I2').setValue('=ImportJSONBasicAuth("http://*****:8080/json.htm?type=devices&rid=68";"**";"**";"/result")');
```

Comment: it is not updating after 30 minutes

Answer (score 1):

- go to **File**
- select **Spreadsheet settings...**
- change recalculation like this:

[image: 9]

- you can test it with this formula:

```
=IF(SECOND(NOW())={00;01;02;03;04;05;06;07;08;09;
                   10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;
                   20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;
                   30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;
                   40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;
                   50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59}, RAND(), RAND())
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a formula to a spreadsheet, instead of `setValue(formula)` use `setFormula(formula)`. For details on how to use this method please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula.

Google Sheets isn't recalculating because the formula because it is exactly the same and due to Google Apps Script / Google Sheets optimization algorithms that is being ignored. To fix this your code should clear the formula, then use `Spreadsheet.flush()` to apply the change to the spreadsheet, then add the formula to the cell.

Remark:

In this case, the formula include a custom function, `ImportJSONBasicAuth`. There is a [famous open source project](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) that include a function of the same name. This famous project also include an advanced function that could be used to do the same that `ImportJSONBasicAuth`. This function could be used instead of the custom function to be called by a time-driven trigger.

Related

- [How to make that a custom function update its result immediately](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109054/88163)
- [How to update this formula so it automatically updates?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122810/88163)